# How to make segment control know which contact user it is associated with?

Tags: react-native

In my react native 0.59 app, I would like to display a list of contact users with its name and its role (like `admin` or `messenger`) for selection (with checkbox). The segment control tab is used to display 3 roles to choose from. Here is the render code I come up:

```
import {CheckBox, View } from 'react-native';
import SegmentedControlTab from 'react-native-segmented-control-tab';

render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.contacts.map((cb) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                <CheckBox
                                    key={cb.id}
                                    title={cb.contact_for.name}
                                    checked={cb._checked}
                                    onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(cb.id)} />
                                <SegmentedControlTab
                                    values={['messenger', 'eventer', 'admin']}
                                    selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                                    onTabPress={this.handleIndexChange}
                                    tabsContainerStyle={styles.tabContainerStyle}
                                />
                                </View>
                                )
                            })}        
            <Button
            title='Save'
            onPress={this.save}
            />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem with this render code is that the segment does not know which contact user it is associated with. How can I make the segment know which contact user it is associated with?

Comment: What is value of `cb.contact_for.name` ?

Comment: It is a string of a contact name.

Comment: Is there any data in your data that can be separated into SegmentedControlTab's value?

Comment: db.id can be used as unique identifier. The segment module used in the app has 3 values of the tabs which are the same across every checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When needed to have interactions between elements that are shown inside a list item, the best approach is often to create one new React component that will represent your list item.

With this pattern, you will have to make the save action at each line, possibly with one button per line... but you can also save data as soon as the data changes (which provides a better UX in my mind)***

Here is a draft. Your list become as follow :

```
import {View } from 'react-native';
import {MyContactListItem} from 'myContactListItem.js';

render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.contacts.map((cb) => {
                            return (
                                <MyContactListItem contact={cb}/>
                                )
                            })}   
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And the other component `MyContactListItem` look like bellow. The `handleIndexChange` will then be able to know which contact it is refering to, as you can find `contact` in the component `props`

```
import {CheckBox, View } from 'react-native';
import SegmentedControlTab from 'react-native-segmented-control-tab';

render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
               <CheckBox
                   key={contact.id}
                   title={contact.contact_for.name}
                   checked={contact._checked}
                   onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(contact.id)} />
               <SegmentedControlTab
                   values={['messenger', 'eventer', 'admin']}
                   selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                   onTabPress={this.handleIndexChange}
                   tabsContainerStyle={styles.tabContainerStyle}/>
            </View>  
            <Button
            title='Save'
            onPress={this.save}
            />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Another option if you absolutely need to keep that unique save button is to manage an array containing the state of each control you need to save when pushing the button. You should limit the use of this option to lists that have a maximum size which is pretty low (i.e. a list that could fit in your screen)

***edit : actually it's possible to keep the unique save button in the parent component, but it will be quite a mess to manage: you will need to send to the list component the info that the state has changed in `MyContactListItem` for contact with the id `id` and then manage an array of changes. I wouldn't go this way...

Comment: The segment still does not know which cp it is associated with. `onTabPress` in segment tab only takes one index (index of user selection such as 0, 1 or 2) as input. .

Comment: In the `onTabPress` function, `this` should have `props`, which should contain `contact`. Hence you should be able to use `this.props.contact.id` to identify the contact in the `onTabPress` function. Have you tried ?